# What does it mean if my confidence interval includes zero with a significant p value in linear regression analysis?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, p-value, linear

I performed linear regression analysis to assess the associations between continuous variables. I found a significant p-value but my confidence interval includes zero. What does it mean? Here are the results;

β= -0.267

SE: 0.000

95 CI= -0.002 to 0.000

p=0.000

[image: Results]

Comment: This output seems to be unrelated to the question, because there is no interval shown that includes zero.  The two intervals are $[0.7, 2.1]$ and $[-0.0017, -0.0004]$.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the screenshot. The *unstandardized* coefficient is $-0.00108$ (rounded to three significant digits) with a corresponding 95% confidence interval of $(-0.00172; -0.000445)$ and a $p$-value of $0.000996$. The $p$-value is below $0.05$ and correspondingly, the 95% confidence interval does not include $0$. There is no contradiction.

The *standardized* coefficient is $-0.267$ but a confidence interval is not provided for this coefficient. The $p$-value does not change, however. If you're interested in calculating a confidence interval for the standardized coefficient, I have summarized the steps in my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/442904/21054) to another post.

As @NickCox rightly states: The predictor is probably on a large scale which leads to very small coefficients and confidence limits because the coefficients are for an increase in 1 unit. To get the change per $x$ units, divide the predictor by $x$ before calculating the regression. For example: If the predictor is money in US dollars, divide by 1000 to calculate the change for an increase in \$1000.

Comment: This. Plus there is a  presentation problem here. To avoid absurd numbers of decimal places, divide your predictor by some convenient number such as 1 thousand or 1 million.